# Log in issues with Astersik

Tags: asterisk, sip, freepbx

I just tried to get into Astersik and FreePBX because I'd like to set up a office phone network with different extensions for different people.

So I took a Raspberry Pi 3, downloaded the image [here](http://www.raspberry-asterisk.org/downloads/) and followed [this documentation](http://www.raspberry-asterisk.org/documentation/). I thought for testing it should be fine.

It was so. Everything worked, no errors or something else while installation. So I opened the FreePBX site in my browser, logged in as admin, created a new user, a new Chain_SIP extension and linked both. Submitted this and applied the config (the red button in the right upper corner). I logged out, logged in with the credentials of the new user in FreePBX admin interface and the UCP interface. Everything was still fine.

Now I wanted to connect via a client to it and chose Empathy and came back to reality. I wasn't able to connect. Astersik full log tells me:

> [2016-11-24 19:07:08] NOTICE[2004] chan_sip.c: Registration from
>   '' failed for '192.168.0.54:34061' - Wrong
>   password

I used that password which was shown during the process to create the extension. I tried the user (not the extension) credentials too, which didn't work and returned the same error, only **1003** is replaced by the user name.

Somewhere I found the command

> asterisk -rx "sip show users"

which returns:

> Username   Secret   Accountcode   Def.Context   ACL   Forcerport
>
> 1003      12345678               from-internal  Yes   Yes

I'm sure, I missed something, but I have no ides what.

Could someone help me?

Comment: You've misconfigured your endpoint. Consult the documentation for how to set up an account.

Answer (score -1):

In FreePBX terminology user <> extension look at http://wiki.freepbx.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5242941 for details. I believe, in your case you need to

```
asterisk -rx "sip show peers"
```

not

```
asterisk -rx "sip show users"
```